# Triangular prism in a sphere

Tags: geometry, spheres

A sphere of unit radius touches all edges of some triangular prism. What can be the volume of this prism?

The prism is regular because it is inscribed in the sphere. We express the radius by the Pythagorean theorem $1=\sqrt{(0,5 a)^{2}+\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^{2}}$. So, $a_{1}=-\frac{2 \sqrt{21}}{7}, a_{2}=\frac{2 \sqrt{21}}{7}$. And we have $\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{21}}{7}\right)^{2} \times 0,5 \times \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{7}$. Then the answer is $\frac{18 \sqrt{7}}{49}$. Am I right?

Comment: The sphere touches the edges of the prism, right? If so, each edge has a length of $\sqrt3$.

Comment: You have computed the volume of a wrong prism (an equilateral triangular prism which have a circumsphere with unit radius). What you are asked to compute is the volume of a triangular prism which have a [midsphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midsphere) with unit radius. (you can ask [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=triangular+prism+with+midsphere) for a picture). The prism you need is equilateral (ie. all sides has same length) with side $\sqrt{3}$ and volume $\frac94$.

Answer (score 1):

If the edge length is $2 a $, then the circumcircle of the the triangular face (which is an equilateral triangle) is

$ R = \sqrt{ 1^2 - a^2 }$

but $ R = \dfrac{2a}{\sqrt{3}} $

Hence, $1 - a^2 = \dfrac{4 a^2}{3} $

making $a^2 = \dfrac{3}{7} $

The volume is $(2 a) \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4} (4 a^2) = (6) (\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{7}}) \dfrac{3}{7} = \dfrac{ 18 }{7 \sqrt{7}} = \dfrac{ 18 \sqrt{7}}{49} $